# Макрос в vba(excel) не работает. Когда нажимаю удалить выдаётся ошибка Type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Лист1")
Dim selected_row As Long
selected_row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng(Me.TextBox8.Value), 
sh.Range("A:A"), 0)
sh.Range("A" & selected_row).EntireRow.Delete
Call Refresh
end sub
```

Вот такой код я написал, но когда я нажимаю удалить выдаётся ошибка Type mismatch. Этот макрос нужен для удаления данных из таблицы.

Comment: *когда я нажимаю удалить выдаётся ошибка Type mismatch.* В каком именно месте кода выдаётся сообщение об ошибке? чему в этот момент равны ВСЕ используемые в строке переменные и свойства? И поправьте код - сейчас он синтаксически неверен вследствие лишнего перевода строки

Comment: selected_row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng(Me.TextBox8.Value), sh.Range("A:A"), 0) На этой строке у меня выдаётся ошибка. При этом selected_row имеет значение 0, а sh - Nothing

Comment: Если `sh - Nothing`, то ошибка должна была возникнуть при записи имени листа в переменную, `selected_row = 0` - `Match` должна была выдать ошибку.  Запишите в начале модуля (перед всеми макросами) *`Option Explicit`*. Это поможет выявить ошибки в коде

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была из-за невнимательности

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Dim Selected_Row As Long
Selected_Row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng(Me.TextBox9.Value), 
sh.Range("A:A"), 0)
sh.Range("A" & Selected_Row).EntireRow.Delete
Call Refresh_Data
```

End Sub